# How to construct index for a text search query in postgres with several OR

Tags: postgresql, indexing, text-search

An external connector creates a very bad request on my postgres database. But it's a business requirement and unfortunately, I cannot change the request.

The request looks like this

```
SELECT avantage.id
FROM avantage 
WHERE (CAST(avantage.web_prepaye_cda_codepin AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true
OR (CAST(avantage.type AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.statut AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.soustype AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.source AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.prepaye_cda_codepin AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.typedeclenchement__c AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.receivedby__c AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.givenby__c AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%')  = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.numero_ticket AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.numero_carte AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.nom_avantage AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.last_modified_by AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.id_carte AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.icu AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.description AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.account_id AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
OR (CAST(avantage.created_by AS TEXT) LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%') = true 
ORDER BY  avantage.id LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0;
```

I tried to add Gin indexes on each fields like this:

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_avantage_web_prepaye_cda_codepin_idx
  ON avantage
  USING gin
  (CAST(web_prepaye_cda_codepin AS TEXT)  COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops);
...
...
```

individually it works well.

And It works well with 5 to 7 conditions (depending of the chosen conditions). 
But with more conditions, Postgres stop using the indices and create a classical very long filter query :

```
 Limit  (cost=0.09..217.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=15952.773..15952.773 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using avantage_pkey on avantage  (cost=0.09..546295.48 rows=2513 width=8) (actual time=15952.771..15952.771 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: (((web_prepaye_cda_codepin)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((type)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((statut)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((soustype)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((source)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((prepaye_cda_codepin)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((typedeclenchement__c)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((receivedby__c)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((givenby__c)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((numero_ticket)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((numero_carte)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((nom_avantage)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((last_modified_by)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((id_carte)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((icu)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((description)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((account_id)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text) OR ((created_by)::text ~~ '%searchword%'::text))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 8028920
 Planning time: 0.922 ms
 Execution time: 15952.814 ms
```

Is there any limit I don't know on the maximum index scan possible in a query ? 
Is there another way to optimize the query without touching it ?

Comment: You can't change the request, or do they just want the desired outcome?
I think the problem is in the casting. Would it be possible to cast the input instead of the (entire) dataset?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `where (x like '...') = true` can be simplified to `where x like '...'`

Comment: Can you compare this query performance?
SELECT avantage.id
FROM avantage 
WHERE
avantage.web_prepaye_cda_codepin || avantage.type || avantage.statut || avantage.soustype || avantage.source || avantage.prepaye_cda_codepin || avantage.typedeclenchement__c || avantage.receivedby__c || avantage.givenby__c || avantage.numero_ticket || avantage.numero_carte || avantage.nom_avantage || avantage.last_modified_by || avantage.id_carte || avantage.icu || avantage.description || avantage.account_id || avantage.created_by LIKE '%' || 'searchword' || '%'
ORDER BY avantage.id LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0;

Comment: Sorry guys, the request is auto generated by a connector. I just can not do anything on it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
ORDER BY avantage.id + 0
```

so that PostgreSQL cannot use the index scan it does because it estimates the number of results wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there is a limit, but you are not running into it.  PostgreSQL can create a BitmapOr with 1000 bitmap index scans if it wants. I don't know how much higher than that you can go, but you can only have 1600 columns in a table so that would put a practical limit on things.

It eventually changes plans simply because it thinks (erroneously, it appears) that the other one will be faster.  Each additional OR makes the planner think it will be dealing with more rows in the result, which makes using the primary key index (to avoid the sort and enable early stopping) look more and more attractive.

If you can't touch the query in any way, what can you touch?  Could you wrap the query in `set enable_indexscan = off; <this query>; reset enable_indexscan;`

Can you get rid of the primary key?  If it is only used to maintain uniqueness, and not in queries or for foreign keys, perhaps you could replace it with a UNIQUE index on (id+0).

Perhaps you could set enable_indexscan off globally, or just for this one user (`alter user user_name set enable_indexscan=off`)?  That is not very desirable, but you are scraping the bottom of the barrel here.  Most index scans would just convert to bitmap scans, and their performance would not change very much.  The problems would be that index-only scans would also be disabled, as well as using indexes to achieve ordering, and bitmap scans are not an effective replacement for either of those.  But maybe you don't really rely on those things.

There are also ways to use connection poolers to intercept and rewrite queries.  Maybe you could use something like there.  I have not used any of them, so can't recommend any.  I know of pgbouncer-rr.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot even wrap the query. 
My thought is also that postgres make a mistake in plannification because plannification of request is longer with all the indices than without them.

Comment: Do you mean the time take to plan, or the size of the plan tree itself in memory?  I don't think either is relevant, it is just the estimated number of rows.  I've edited to describe that, and some more (less desirable) options.

Comment: I don't really know. I just know taht with more than 5 to 7 conditions, postgres start to ignore the indices.